# Passing multiple command arguments in single argument to shell function

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to have a function in which I execute command (for example `make`) and **one** argument of that function can be a string with **multiple** arguments for that command.

Here's an example of a failing script which demonstrates what I would like to achieve:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e
set -u
set -v
set -x
buildSomething() {
    make ${1}
}

buildSomething "CFLAGS=\"-DX=1 -DY=1\" CXXFLAGS=\"-DXX=11 -DYY=11\" -j$(nproc)"
```

This fails because shell decides to quote the arguments again:

```
buildSomething "CFLAGS=\"-DX=1 -DY=1\" CXXFLAGS=\"-DXX=11 -DYY=11\" -j$(nproc)"
nproc
++ nproc
+ buildSomething 'CFLAGS="-DX=1 -DY=1" CXXFLAGS="-DXX=11 -DYY=11" -j8'
+ make 'CFLAGS="-DX=1' '-DY=1"' 'CXXFLAGS="-DXX=11' '-DYY=11"' -j8
make: invalid option -- 'D'
make: invalid option -- 'Y'
make: invalid option -- '='
make: invalid option -- '1'
make: invalid option -- '"'
make: invalid option -- 'D'
make: invalid option -- 'Y'
make: invalid option -- 'Y'
make: invalid option -- '='
make: invalid option -- '1'
make: invalid option -- '1'
make: invalid option -- '"'
```

I know that the problem is with quoting, but I think I've tried all combinations that I could think of... Is there any generic solution to this problem? I don't insist on fixing this exact script above, a different approach that would allow me to do the thing mentioned in the first paragraph would also be ok. As such function would have multiple commands, each can have its arguments in a different argument of the function, it's really important for me to have **multiple** arguments for each command in **one** function argument (or something equivalent).

Comment: did you try `make "${1}" ...` ? Then just call as `buildSomething "CFLAGS=-DX=1 -DY=1 .... "` ? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter - this example indeed worked as intended with your change, so I updated the post with a more complex scenario - the argument cannot be quoted there, as I need to pass **multiple** arguments, and quoting them at the call of command merges them all into one (invalid) argument. I'm currently trying out `eval make ...` - seems like a good solution, but maybe there's something better.

Comment: and you know about `${@}` and `"${@}"` ?  .... `eval` is usually considered evil, but in your case it may be your only option. Good luck.

Comment: Is there a reason you chose this calling convention? The usual (best) option is "don't". `buildSomething CFLAGS="-DX=1 -DY=1" CXXFLAGS="-DXX=11 -DYY=11" -j8` would avoid this mess, letting you call `make "$@"` to pass everything through. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) re: best practices around constructing argument lists (and alternatives to using strings).

Comment: BTW, `set -e` is not considered good practice inside the bash community -- see [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105), skipping to the exercises below the allegory if in a hurry; and the list of incompatibilities given at https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

buildSomething() {
    eval "make ${1}"
}

buildSomething 'CFLAGS=\"-DX=1 -DY=1\" CXXFLAGS=\"-DXX=11 -DYY=11\"'" -j$(nproc)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a safer way:

```
#!/bin/sh

buildSomething() {
    echo ${1} | xargs make
}

buildSomething 'CFLAGS=\"-DX=1 -DY=1\" CXXFLAGS=\"-DXX=11 -DYY=11\"'" -j$(nproc)"
```

Comment: `xargs make <<<"$1"` would be better, but even that's only a limited value of "safe".